# Foundry: Veirfy contracts on deployment with config in foundry.toml

Tags: etherscan, foundry, verify, contract-verification

Ok so I'm using Foundry to deploy contracts to multiple networks (Ethereum and L2s). I use the `--verify` option to verify on deployment. On goerli network the contracts get verified automatically on deployment. On Arbitrum Goerli, veirfication fails with the error

```
Encountered an error verifying this contract:
Response: `NOTOK`
Details: `Invalid API Key`
```

I run forge this way to deploy the contracts:

```
forge script ./script/DeployContracts.s.sol --rpc-url $RPC_URL --broadcast --verify -vvv
```

Here's my foundry.toml file

```
[rpc_endpoints]
mainnet = "${ETH_RPC_URL}"
goerli = "${GOERLI_RPC_URL}"
arbitrum = "${ARB_RPC_URL}"
arbitrum_goerli = "${ARB_GOERLI_RPC_URL}"

[etherscan]
goerli = { key = "${ETHERSCAN_API_KEY}" }
mainnet = { key = "${ETHERSCAN_MAINNET_KEY}" }
arbitrum = { key = "${ARBISCAN_API_KEY}" }
arbitrum-goerli = { key = "${ARBISCAN_API_KEY}", url="https://api-goerli.arbiscan.io/api" }
...
```

I can probably verify the contracts using `forge verify-contract ...` after deployment, but that would complicate the workflow since I'd be deploying several contracts to different networks so would be simpler to verify them on deployment.

So the specific question is the a way to specify the arbitrum goerli configuration int he `foundry.toml` file so contracts verify automatically on deployment?